# Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_array_new_length at memory location 0x00F9FA88. What is wrong?

Tags: c++

It's just a struct

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS //def 

#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>


using namespace std;
```

my struct

```
struct muncitor  
{
    int id;
    char *nume;
    float salariu;
    char init_t;
    bool fct_conducere;
    int nr_calificativ;
    int *calificativ;
};
```

reading struct content

```
void read(muncitor m) 
{

    cout << "Id: ";
    cin >> m.id;

    cout << "numele: ";
    char aux[20];
    cin >> aux;
    m.nume = new char[strlen(aux) + 1];
    strcpy(m.nume, aux);

    cout << "salariul: ";
    cin >> m.salariu;

    cout << "initiala: ";
    cin >> m.init_t;

    cout << "functie: ";
    cin >> m.fct_conducere;

    cout << "nr calificative: ";
    cin >> m.nr_calificativ;
    cout << m.nr_calificativ << " ";

    m.calificativ = new int[m.nr_calificativ]; here is the problem

    for (int i = 0; i < m.nr_calificativ; i++)
    {
        cout << "calificativul: ";
        cin >> m.calificativ[i];
    }

}

void main()
{

    muncitor m;

    m.id = 1;
    m.salariu = 1250;

    read(m); //call void
    _getch;
}
```

Can't figure it out. The debug stops at `m.calificativ = new int[m.nr_calificativ];`
What is wrong? Please help me. A test is coming soon. I can't find a solution, so I'm asking here.

Comment: What is in `m.nr_calificativ`?

Comment: @ScottHunter its declared on the struct

Comment: @LorenceHernandez he's asking about value. Could you supply the result of "cout << m.nr_calificativ << " "; ?

Comment: it's the number of grades(="calificative" in my language)

Comment: @AndreiB: What is the actual NUMBER?

Comment: I don't have a fixed number, I just want to read it from the user and use it in that for

Comment: But what is the actual NUMBER in this case where it breaks?  Your debugger should let you find the value.  Suspect an error in reading the value.

Comment: -858993460 int type

Comment: @AndreiB Well that'll do it.

Comment: cin is not able to convert "true"/"false" strings to actual bool values. Use 1 or 0. Also, the right signature of read should be void read(muncitor& m).